# Where is a good place to grind to level 99?

Tags: nier-automata

I'm trying to get a weapon so that I can upgrade it to the maximum level like all the other weapons so that I can

> unlock the super-secret boss, Emil, to get ending Y.

However, to get this weapon, I need to beat a very difficult boss. Unfortunately for me, he is level 99, while I am roughly level 70. I tried my luck at his fight, but after an arduous 25 minute battle, he whipped out a move I hadn't seen before and one-shot me.

Considering my Pod was doing 1 damage per shot and I was doing no more than 50 per hit, it's pretty obvious I need to grind some levels to at least have a fighting chance against this guy. However, enemies tend to be spread out, so I can't think of any one good place to grind levels for a while. Where would I be able to level up quickly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe I've found the best possible way to farm levels in this game. As mentioned in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168677-nier-automata/75114978), the giant golden bunny statue at the front of the Amusement Park is actually a level 80 enemy.

> Pleasantly surprised to find out that big machine life-form statue with the horn and bunny ears in the amusement park is actually a living enemy. [...] It's a level 80 enemy and it's really only feasible to defeat it by hacking it. Which you want to do because each successful hack on it netted about 11,000 exp. 2 hacks + it dying got me like 50,000 exp (slightly amp'd by my Exp +5 plugin chip). Went from level 66 to level 70 from one easy foe.

You may have to attack it for a few minutes before it notices you and starts moving (you won't even see a health bar before then). Once it starts moving, the easiest way to kill it is by hacking it as 9S.

When I just tried this with an EXP Gain +6 chip equipped, I received 13,000+ EXP for the first hack and 14,000+ EXP for the second, then a ridiculous ~50,000 EXP for defeating it. I leveled from 69 to 74 in roughly 4 minutes.

[Here's a video of the entire thing.](https://youtu.be/-XxDobJ8aSU)

Side note: while waiting for the video to upload, I defeated it a second time and boosted to level 77.

Update: It took less than an hour total to boost from level 69 to 99 using this method.

Comment: If you hack into a nearby machine and Remote Control it, you can hack directly into the Rabbit without having to do any of that attacking. The tall friendly robots nearby are the best bet as they have high damage output and fast move speed. The damage is useful for clearing out the surrounding courtyard, as for some reason landing the reticule on that statue is very difficult.

Comment: @CraigWright I read that but I couldn't get it to work :/

Comment: It does work. It helps to clear out the zone. You really have to wiggle around to find the reticule on the rabbit. I am on PS4. Question: how do you reload the encounter? Chapter Select, or just Transport? Do you have a recommended Chapter for farming this spot?

Comment: @CraigWright I used Transport. I was also farming materials to max out weapons so I'd alternate between my farming route and taking out the bunny. It worked pretty well. I ended up having to only farm at the end though, because I hit level 99 much faster than I got all the materials I needed.

Comment: Actually at around level 80 yourself, 2b can kill it pretty easily. Just don't let it hit you too much.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to going to Desert: Housing Complex in the place that fight the Adam boss, you have to fight the boss Adam first, then go back to that place again. There are a dozen of enemy that already lv. 30 or more. The enemy seems strong enough and always keep spawn in there. I think it should gain the level up faster.

Comment: Unless you gain 5-6 levels at a time, I really don't think it's faster...